# ¿Como solucionar un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, array, excepciones

Tengo que hacer un programa que tiene 4 clases, class UNAHUR, class Comision, class Docente y class Estudiante. Fui haciendo los constructores de cada clase tratando de que el usuario pueda ingresar todos los datos. El problema está cuando ingreso los datos de los docentes por teclado.
Este es el código completo de todas las clases:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Estudiante 
{
    String nombre;
    int legajo;
            
    public Estudiante()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ");
        String n = scan.nextLine();
        this.nombre = n;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el legajo del estudiante: ");
        int l = scan.nextInt();
        this.legajo = l;
    }


    import java.util.*;


public class Docente 
    {
        String nombre;
        int dni;
        
        public Docente()
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del docente: ");
            String n = scan.nextLine();
            this.nombre = n;
            System.out.println("Ingrese el dni del docente: ");
            int d = scan.nextInt();
            this.dni = d;
        }

import java.util.*;

public class Comision 
{
    String materia;
    int numero;
    Docente[] docentes;
    Estudiante[] inscriptos;
    int[] calificaciones;
    
    public Comision()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Creando comision...");
        System.out.print("Materia: ");
        String m = scan.next();
        this.materia = m;
        System.out.print("Numero: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        this.numero = n;
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de docentes: ");
        int cantD = scan.nextInt();
        this.docentes = new Docente[cantD];
        System.out.println(this.docentes.length);
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes inscriptos: ");
        int cantE = scan.nextInt();
        this.inscriptos = new Estudiante[cantE];
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones: ");
        int cantC = scan.nextInt();
        this.calificaciones = new int[cantC];
    }
    
    
    
    public void setDocentes()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Desea ingresar un docente? (si/no)");
        String respuesta = scan.next();
        respuesta = respuesta.toLowerCase();
        for(int i=0;(respuesta.equals("si")&&i<=docentes.length);i++)
        {
            Docente d1 = new Docente();
            this.docentes[i]=d1;
            System.out.println("Desea ingresar otro docente? (si/no)");
            respuesta = scan.next();
            respuesta = respuesta.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
        
    public void setEstudiantes()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
        System.out.println("Desea ingresar un estudiante? (si/no)");
        String respuesta = scan.next();
        respuesta = respuesta.toLowerCase();
        for(int i=0;respuesta.equals("si")&&i<=inscriptos.length;i++)
        {
            Estudiante e1 = new Estudiante();
            this.inscriptos[i]=e1;
            System.out.println("Desea ingresar otro estudiante? (si/no)");
            respuesta = scan.next();
            respuesta = respuesta.toLowerCase();
        }
        
    }
    public void setCalificaciones ()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<this.calificaciones.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(inscriptos[i].nombre);
            System.out.println("Ingrese la calificacion");
            int calif = scan.nextInt();
            this.calificaciones[i]=calif;
        }
    }
        
}

import java.util.*;

public class UNAHUR extends Comision
{
    Comision[] comisiones;
    
    UNAHUR(int cant)
    {
        this.comisiones = new Comision[cant];
        for(int i=0; i<cant-1;i++)
        {
            Comision comision = new Comision();
            this.comisiones[i] = comision;
        }
        
    }
```

Ademas de esas clases, cree otra para poder probar el programa:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal 
{
    public static void insertarMenu()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.println("MENU PRINCIPAL");   
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion a realizar.");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("a. Ingresar Docentes.");
        System.out.println("b. Ingresar Estudiantes.");
        System.out.println("c. Ingresar Calificaciones.");
        System.out.println("d. Con quien curso?");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de comisiones: ");
        int cant = scan.nextInt();
        UNAHUR u = new UNAHUR(cant);
        System.out.println("Desea ir al menu principal? (si/no)");
        String menu = scan.next();
        menu = menu.toLowerCase();
        while (menu.equals("si"))
        {
            insertarMenu();
            String r = scan.next();
            r = r.toLowerCase();
            
            if (r.equals("a"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese numero de comision: ");
                int comision = scan.nextInt();
                u.comisiones[comision-1].setDocentes();
            }else if(r.equals("b"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese numero de comision: ");
                int comision = scan.nextInt();
                u.comisiones[comision-1].setEstudiantes();
            }else if(r.equals("c"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese numero de comision: ");
                int comision = scan.nextInt();
                u.comisiones[comision-1].setCalificaciones();
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("Opcion incorrecta.");
            }
                
            
            System.out.println("Desea volver al menu principal? (si/no)");
            menu = scan.next();
            menu = menu.toLowerCase();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Al correr el programa pasa lo siguiente, aparece un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException antes de que me pregunte si quiero ingresar otro docente. Parece que no toma que la longitud del array es de 2 y puedo encontrar la solución.

```
Ingrese la cantidad de comisiones: 
2
Creando comision...
Materia: matematica
Numero: 1
Ingrese la cantidad de docentes: 2
2
Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes inscriptos: 3
Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones: 3
Creando comision...
Materia: literatura
Numero: 2
Ingrese la cantidad de docentes: 1
1
Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes inscriptos: 3
Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones: 3
Desea ir al menu principal? (si/no)
si
MENU PRINCIPAL
 
Seleccione una opcion a realizar.
 
a. Ingresar Docentes.
b. Ingresar Estudiantes.
c. Ingresar Calificaciones.
d. Con quien curso?
a
Ingrese numero de comision: 
1
Desea ingresar un docente? (si/no)
si
Ingrese el nombre del docente: 
sofia
Ingrese el dni del docente: 
112
Desea ingresar otro docente? (si/no)
si
Ingrese el nombre del docente: 
juan
Ingrese el dni del docente: 
445
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at Practica2Ej07.Comision.setDocentes(Comision.java:50)
    at Practica2Ej07.Principal.main(Principal.java:41)
```

Comment: un Array tiene tamaño estático es decir mantiene el tamaño con el que fue declarado inicialmente ,al ingresar cantidad de docentes pusiste 1 por ende solo podes ingresar 1 docente,es lógico que si ingresas un segundo docente en este caso juan te arroje esa excepcion

Comment: ¿Ya buscaste por qué se origina el error? ¿Revisaste en [las preguntas del sitio](/search?q=ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ayes)?

Comment: @Dramaturgo En la comisión número 1 puse que eran 2 docentes. Por eso es que no entiendo el error

Comment: pero estas colocando una segunda comisión (literatura ) la cual reemplaza a la primera y en donde pones solo 1 docente ,como programas al sistema para que acceda al array de la comisión matematica?

Comment: Por eso puse comision-1: u.comisiones[**comision-1**].setEstudiantes();

Comment: en la clase UNAHUR no necesitas aplicar extends eso  hace que salte el constructor de comision , aparte tenes un for que genera objetos comision segun la cantidad que ingresas pero pones cant-1 eso hace que solo ingrese 1 osea el ultimo y por ende capture el array docente del ultimo,borra extends y deja el for en i< cant

Answer (score -1):

Modificaciones generales:
Muchas variables se declaraban en una linea e instanciaban en otra, lo simplifique a una. En algunas clases agregué los **geters**.

A la clase UNAHUR, le quite el **extends Comision**, que no tenía razón de ser, y además hacia que se repita la llamada a **Comision**, también quite los **this**.

```
public class UNAHUR {

   Comision[] comisiones;

   public UNAHUR( int cant ) {
      comisiones = new Comision[ cant ];
      for( int i = 0; i < cant; i++ ) {
         comisiones[ i ] = new Comision();
      }
   }
}
```

En **Comision**, creé un método para simplificar el "si o no", declarando un boleano, que se instancia con el mencionado método.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Comision {

   String materia;
   int numero;
   Docente[] docentes;
   Estudiante[] inscriptos;
   int[] calificaciones;
   boolean agregar;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
   
   public Comision() {
      System.out.println( "Creando comision..." );
      System.out.print( "Materia: " );
      materia = scan.next();          
      numero = ingreseNumero( "Numero: " );
      docentes = new Docente[ ingreseNumero( "Ingrese la cantidad de docentes: " ) ];
      inscriptos = new Estudiante[ ingreseNumero( "Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes inscriptos: " ) ];
      calificaciones = new int[ ingreseNumero( "Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones: " ) ];
   }

   public void setDocentes() {
      agregar = true;
      for( int i = 0; agregar && i < docentes.length; i++ ) {
         docentes[ i ] = new Docente(); 
         agregar = si_no( "Desea ingresar otro docente? (si/no)" );
      }
   }

   public void setEstudiantes() {
        agregar = true;
        for( int i = 0; agregar && i < inscriptos.length; i++ ) {
            inscriptos[ i ] = new Estudiante();
            agregar = si_no( "Desea ingresar otro estudiante? (si/no)" );
        }             
   }

   public void setCalificaciones() {
       for( int i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++ ) {
           System.out.println( inscriptos[ i ].nombre );
           calificaciones[ i ] = ingreseNumero( "Ingrese la calificacion" );
       }   
   }
   
   boolean siono( String mensaje ) {
      scan = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.println( mensaje );
      return "si".equals( scan.nextLine().toLowerCase() );
   }

   private int ingreseNumero( String mensaje ) {
      try {
         System.out.print( mensaje );
         int salida = scan.nextInt();
         if( salida < 1 ) {
            System.out.print( "Debes ingresar un número mayor que cero" );
            ingreseNumero( mensaje );
         }
         return salida;
      }
      catch( Exception w ) {
         System.out.print( "Debes ingresar un número entero" );
         ingreseNumero( mensaje );
      }
      return 0;
   }
   
   public String getMateria() {
      return materia;
   }
   
   public int getNumero() {
      return numero;
   }
   
   public Docente[] getDocentes( int cual ) {
      return docentes;
   }
   
   public Estudiante[] getInscriptos() {
      return inscriptos;
   }
   
   public int[] getCalificaciones() {
      return calificaciones;
   }

}
```

La clase Docente

```
import java.util.*;

public class Docente {
   String nombre;
   int dni;

   public Docente() {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del docente: ");
       nombre = scan.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Ingrese el dni del docente: ");
       dni = scan.nextInt();
   }
   
   public String getNombre() {
      return nombre;
   }
   
   public int getDni() {
      return dni;
   }    
}
```

La clase Estudiante

```
import java.util.*;

public class Estudiante {

   String nombre;
   int legajo;

   public Estudiante() {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.println( "Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: " );
      nombre = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println( "Ingrese el legajo del estudiante: " );
      legajo = scan.nextInt();
   }
   
   public String getNombre() {
      return nombre;
   }
   
   public int getLegajo() {
      return legajo;
   }
}
```

Y la clase Principal, que es la que más "ha sufrido".

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal {
   
   public static void insertarMenu() {
      System.out.println( "MENU PRINCIPAL" );
      System.out.println( " " );
      System.out.println( "Seleccione una opcion a realizar." );
      System.out.println( " " );
      System.out.println( "a. Ingresar Docentes." );
      System.out.println( "b. Ingresar Estudiantes." );
      System.out.println( "c. Ingresar Calificaciones." );
      System.out.println( "d. Con quien curso?" );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.println( "Ingrese la cantidad de comisiones: " );
      UNAHUR instituto = new UNAHUR( scan.nextInt() );
      
      boolean quiere = si_no( scan, "Si desea ir al menu principal, escriba \"si\"" );
      System.out.println( "quiere = " + quiere );
      while( quiere ) {
         insertarMenu();
         String opcion = scan.next().toLowerCase();
         String mensaje = "Ingrese numero de comision: ";
         if( opcion.equals( "a" ) ) {            
            instituto.comisiones[ ingreseNumero( scan, mensaje ) - 1 ].setDocentes();
         }
         else if( opcion.equals( "b" ) ) {            
            instituto.comisiones[ ingreseNumero( scan, mensaje ) - 1 ].setEstudiantes();
         }
         else if( opcion.equals( "c" ) ) {
            instituto.comisiones[ ingreseNumero( scan, mensaje ) - 1 ].setCalificaciones();
         }
         else {
            System.out.println( "Opcion incorrecta." );
         }
         quiere = si_no( scan, "Si desea volver al menu principal, escriba \"si\"" );
      }
      scan.close();    
   }
   
   static int ingreseNumero( Scanner scan, String mensaje ) {      
        try {
            System.out.print( mensaje );
            int salida = scan.nextInt();
            if( salida < 1 ) {
                System.out.print( "Debes ingresar un número mayor que cero" );
                ingreseNumero( scan, mensaje );
            }
            return salida;
        }
        catch( Exception w ) {
            System.out.print( "Debes ingresar un número entero" );
            ingreseNumero( scan, mensaje );
        }
        return 0;
     }

     static boolean si_no( Scanner scan, String mensaje ) {  
        scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( mensaje );
        return "si".equals( scan.nextLine().toLowerCase() );
     }
}
```

Tanto en la clase Comisiones como en Principal, creé un método para recibir los números ingresados mediante el scanner, este comprueba que sean válidos y obra en consecuencia.